# как запретить редирект из iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Есть сайт, у меня на нем встраивается в div iframe с другого ресурса (видео).

Когда нажимаешь внутри iframe (видео плеер) на кнопки проиграть и прочие - все нормально. Но если во время проигрывания видео нажать на само видео (с желанием поставить на паузу) то происходит открытие новой вкладки с урлом того ресурса откуда iframe. Вопрос следующий. Возможно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы заблочить этот редирект (открытие в новой вкладке)?

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/

Comment: @labris, что-то несколько раз перечитал - не понятно... =((( очень большое количество информации. Не мог бы ты, пожалуйста, ткнуть пальцем? =))

Comment: В двух словах: запускать iframe с атрибутом sandbox, в нем прописывать, что можно, а что нельзя. В данном случае точно не надо allow-popups, то есть их не разрешать.

Comment: @labris, то есть у меня есть iframe следующего содержания:
<iframe src="https://flashservice.xvideos.com/embedframe/26946297" frameborder=0 width=651 height=398 scrolling=no allowfullscreen=allowfullscreen></iframe> http://www.xvideos.com/video26946297/watching_hentai_with_lana_rain_as_ayanami_rei_full_recording

мне в него надо добавить sandbox="*сюда прописать какие-то запреты*"

правильно я понимаю?
а как прописать туда именно запрет, а не разрешение? В ссылке я нашел только разрешения

Comment: В sandbox все запрещено, поэтому прописывать надо разрешения, остальное само запретится. http://htmlbook.ru/html/iframe/sandbox

Comment: @labris то есть чтобы запретить вообще все, то мне надо просто прописать пустой sandbox, верно?

Comment: Для вашего случая попробуйте sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" и все. В Хроме работает.

Comment: @labris, спасибо огромное =) Получилось =)

Comment: Ну тогда примите ответ :)

Comment: @labris, а как это сделать то? Я вижу только вариант как самому себе ответить и принять его. Можете ответ написать как ответ, а не как комментарий? Тут же вроде какие-то очки или баллы за это присваиваются?

Answer (score 1):

В sandbox все запрещено, поэтому прописывать надо разрешения, остальное само запретится. htmlbook.ru/html/iframe/sandbox

Для вашего случая попробуйте sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" и все. В Хроме работает. – labris